# Flux Query equivalent of InfluxDB query

Tags: influxdb, influxql

I am trying to create two queries that produce the same result with one querying an InfluxDB and the other querying InfluxDB Cloud.

The below query retrieves the mean value of road temperature each day from the past 30 days and groups them by day which allows me to display the data in a graph showing the average road temperature for each day.
[image: Road Temperature Graph]

```
'SELECT mean("value") FROM "' + 'road_temp' + '"WHERE "road_sensor_id"=\'' + str(road_sensor_id)
            + '\' AND time > now() - 30d GROUP BY time(1d)'
```

I'm trying to get the equivalent query for the cloud DB to retrieve the same data. I have tried the below query and variations of it so far.

```
from(bucket: "Cloud_Data")
                |> range(start: -30d, stop: now())
                |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == \"{measurement}\" and r.road_sensor_id == \"{road_sensor_id}\")
                |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)
                |> group(columns:["r._time"])
```

The data from both queries is sent to the graph in the same way and the cloud query has an output as show below.
[image]

Is there something I am missing in the cloud query that is giving me the wrong result?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that last **group** function call:

```
from(bucket: "Cloud_Data")
                |> range(start: -30d, stop: now())
                |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == \"{measurement}\" and r.road_sensor_id == \"{road_sensor_id}\")
                |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: mean, createEmpty: false) // this is good enough
                // |> group(columns:["r._time"])
```

> The aggregateWindow() function allows you to apply a selector (like min, max, median, etc.)  or aggregate function (mean, count, sum, etc.) to your data after grouping by time by the duration specified with the every parameter.